# Chrome extension: execute something in JS console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I build an extension (my pet project) where I click on name of snippet and it will automatically add it to console. I'm stuck because when I use console.log my snippets is already "entered" and after invoking that function it shows reference error:
[image]

The point is - how to write something into a console using event to "paste snippet" without hitting enter?

Comment: Logging something to the console doesn't execute it. So logging a function definition doesn't define the function.

Comment: If you want to execute it, use `eval()`

Comment: You need to expose the following code in page context ([more info](/a/9517879)): `window.checkElemWidth = function checkElemWidth() { ..... }` instead of using console.log.

Answer (score -1):

You'll want to `eval` the output you're logging as well ([but that can be very dangerous with uncontrolled input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#:%7E:text=eval()%20is%20a%20dangerous,permissions%20of%20your%20webpage%20%2F%20extension.)).

For example:

```js
const testFunctionText = `var test = () => console.log(1)`

console.log(testFunctionText)
eval(testFunctionText)

document.getElementById("run").onclick = () => {
    eval(document.getElementById("input").value)
}
```

```html
<input id="input" placeholder="Evaluate console statement (no input on StackOverflow)">
<button id="run">Run</button>
```

With this code snippet, try putting `test()` into the provided input.